# Apple's RAM limit real or "marketing"?

Tags: mac, memory

I have a 21.5" iMac (Late 2009). Apple says that this can handle up to 8GB of RAM. They say that the 27" can handle more (up to 16GB). What happens if I install 16GB? Will it run? Crash? Use only part of it?

EDIT:

I finally called and chatted with Apple (simultaneously) and at first they said that the max is 8GB. After I showed them those documents, they agreed with me. the max is 16GB. (Thanks, Spiff.)

Comment: Does the 27" iMac have the same number of RAM slots, as your 21.5" iMac?

Comment: @mctylr - Yes, it does. Same speed too.

Comment: You know, Apple will _gladly_ sell you 16GB of RAM at $100 per GB. Plus shipping, of course...

Comment: @Joe Internet, sure they would. Where is it cheaper? $100 for a 4GB stick is cheap. (In terms of DDR3 anyways...)

Comment: Weel, it looks like Apple is selling 4GB upgrades for $200...http://store.apple.com/us/memorymodel/ME_IMAC_F09_21. You can do better at Newegg...http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010170381%201309239101%201309121118&name=4GB%20%282%20x%202GB%29

Comment: @Joe Internet - I was thinking Newegg actually. I just need to check TigerDirect. By the way, am I looking for Desktop, or Laptop memory? I don't know what form factor Apple used.

Comment: The first link above is Apple's upgrade page for the latest 21.5" iMac, and it looks like laptop memory to me, but you should check Apple's docs to be certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some places where Apple says it supports 16GB of RAM:

http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html

(The information at the link above still applies to your model temporarily since a new model has not come out yet. The link below is always for your specific model.)

http://support.apple.com/kb/SP576

Comment: As per your links Apple admitted that I need not buy new 27" iMac to get the benefit of buying 16GB of RAM from them.

Answer (score 3):

Typically one of two things happen:

1. It works--sometimes the memory controller can handle that much memory but it was never tested in an official capacity.
2. It doesn't--the chipset can't address the extra memory and you will hit the 8GiB limit. The old Apple machines did this (LC II only seeing 10MiB, anyone?)
3. It catastrophically doesn't--the chipset addresses a significant subset of the memory. You may only see 4GiB.

Best thing to do is to try.